# How to use dynamic element ID with Javascript onClick event for JPlayer

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried to figure this out myself and I usually wont stop until I figure something out. However, this has got me stumped.

Our unique situation involves using a WooCommerce product loop that displays a number of products on our homepage. When a user mouses over a product image, an overlay then displays with a play button, and a few other useful icons.

Upon clicking this play button, our JPlayer should simply play the associated mp3 file. I've figured out how to get it to play the mp3 file, based on the product that is displayed. However, I soon realized that I have to specify a unique ID for each product that is displayed, otherwise the player will not play more than one song on the same page. Hope I haven't lost anyone yet.

So I figured, why not use the post id as the unique identifier? Below is the link tag that I'm using for the play button overlay.

```
<a id="myPlayButton-<?php the_id(); ?>" data-mp3file="<?php echo $file; ?>" data-mp3title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="#">
<i class="icon-control-play i-2x"></i>
</a>
```

As you can see, I'm uniquely identifying this button (and each one in the loop), which generates an ID such as: "myPlayButton-1234"

My issue is that once I have this new ID, I cannot figure out how to use this unique ID in my javascript code. If I simply define a normal ID (something like "myPlayButton"), the code works fine. But it will only play the first song in the loop. I can't figure out how to use that ID above in my code.

Here's the jplayer code that works, but only plays the first song in the loop (because the ID isn't unique for each element):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myPlayButton").click(function () {
             var playbutton = document.getElementById("myPlayButton");
             var mp3id = playbutton.getAttribute('data-mp3file');
             var songtitle = playbutton.getAttribute('data-mp3title');
                 $("#jplayer_N").jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: mp3id, title: songtitle}).jPlayer("play");
         });
</script>
```

And here's the jplayer code we're trying to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("<?php echo '#myPlayButton-'.the_id(); ?>").click(function () {
             var playbutton = document.getElementById("<?php echo 'myPlayButton-'.the_id(); ?>");
             var mp3id = playbutton.getAttribute('data-mp3file');
             var songtitle = playbutton.getAttribute('data-mp3title');
                 $("#jplayer_N").jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: mp3id, title: songtitle}).jPlayer("play");
         });
</script>
```

I read somewhere that I can input php code inside of my javascript in the way that I did above. However, the play button simply does not work. I have tried many different methods to get that unique ID into my JS, but nothing works.

I need a way to pass the unique ID to the script so that I can get the play button to work on each post/product in the loop. Also, if it helps to know, I am including this small script in right before the closing BODY tag in my footer. If I put it anywhere else, it doesn't work. Perhaps I'm not using it in the right place?

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? If I haven't included enough info, I apologize. I'm new to this site. I've been a lurker for quite a while.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You don't need a unique identifier. Between using a `class` and your `data` attribute you can get your hovers to work and play unique content.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I've seen some snippets on the web that used a similar approach. I'll try that out. In the meantime, could you give me a quick example? Instead of using the ID in the document.getElementById tag, I would use a class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class instead of `id`. See if this works:

```
<a class="mybutton" data-mp3file="<?php echo $file; ?>" data-mp3title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="#">
<i class="icon-control-play i-2x"></i>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".mybutton").click(function () {
    // Using $(this) targets the specific clicked element
    var playbutton  =   $(this);
    // Append your object and use .data()
    var mp3id       =   playbutton.data('mp3file');
    // Append your object and use .data()
    var songtitle   =   playbutton.data('mp3title');
    // Should need no change to this line
    $("#jplayer_N").jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: mp3id, title: songtitle }).jPlayer("play");
});
</script>
```

Comment: This was absolutely the solution. You fixed it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem! Anytime you can use `$(this)` you will make your life much easier! I have found it's one of the most important aspects of javascript/jQuery because it easily identifies a unique element without specifically naming it.

Comment: Wonderful information, thanks again. I'm new to JS and trying my best to get involved and learn the language. Keep up the good work, man.